# How to hold or sleep a http request till some processing is done on the server side?

Tags: java, .net, node.js, http

I have a web application. The UI client triggers an http request to the server. 
The server has to hold the response for couple of seconds before it sends the response. This holding time - is to contact some other third party service. We send a request to third party service and poll on it for couple of seconds for every 1sec to see some specific state. After this loop ends then send the response of the UI client.
So

```
var state = send request to third party
while(state = "poll" ) {
   do I need to sleep the current thread like sleep(currentThread, 1sec) ? 
   call third party again to know the state.
}
```

How usually developers do that to achieve this ?
If we block the current http thread, is there any effect on the entire server. Will it cause any problem for other requests.

1. www.test.com
2. enter user name and password - POST
3. server validates in it local database, 
   sends a request to third party app to get some quotation related to his username.

   1. create quotation request - response received with state : "BEING PREPARED"
   2. get quoation - "BEING PREAPRED"
   3. wait/sleep for 1second
   4. get quoation - "BEING PREAPRED"
   5. wait/sleep for 1second
   6. get quoation - "BEING PREAPRED"
   7. wait/sleep for 1second
   8. get quoation - "COMPLETE"
4. send response as JSON.

The same can be done a different way.

1. www.test.com
2. enter user name and password - POST
3. server validates in it local database, 
   sends a request to third party app to get some quotation related to his username.

   1. create quotation request - response received with state : "BEING PREPARED"
   2. store the request_id in db.
4. send response as JSON
5. poll to the server with request_id
6. "BEING PREAPRED"
7. setTimeout(1sec)
8. poll to the server with request_id
9. "BEING PREAPRED"
10. setTimeout(1sec)
11. poll to the server with request_id
12. "BEING PREAPRED"
13. setTimeout(1sec)
14. poll to the server with request_id
15. "COMPLETE"

There is a different between both the cases.

First one, I am not flooding my webserver with http calls every one second. rather I am holding first http request and wait for response from quoation service then process the response.
my question is how can I hold or make that request thread to sleep for that 1sec frequency.

second one, is a continuous polling which floods the webserver.

Comment: callback is a way of doing that.

Comment: Can someone answer this for .Net and Java based app.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is interesting, but far from efficient. When developing a web application there are more elegant ways of reporting process status. Take a peek at SignalR or SocketIO for example. This way you don't have to maintain an open connection to the server, but status of work is pushed to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is single threaded by nature, We use Promises to wait until we have not received response from other third party services.

```
async function apiController(req, res){
      const response = await request.get('http://...........)
      res.status(200).json({...})
```

this function basically waits in eventLoop to get response from above api Call allowing main thread to be free and to be used for other tasks

Answer (score 0):

A couple aspects to your question:

(1) Can your web server do this? Yes, of course, easily. Any popular HTTP server framework (like `express`) uses asynchronous callbacks for handling request/response. So, you can easily just have the response not sent until you've received the information you need from a third party API.

Pseudocode example using promises with express:

```
app.get('/myurl', function (req, res) {
    makeApiRequest().then(result => {
        // We reach here after we are all done with the API.
        res.send('here is a response to browser using data from result');
    });
});

async function makeApiRequest() {
    // here, make the API request, do a polling loop, etc.
    // eventually return the result
}
```

(2) Should you do it? It's actually very common for a request to a web server to *block while waiting for third party API responses* - however, you need to be careful with this. A response time stretching above 750ms is going to be considered slow by many users. So, you really want any given third party API response to take 100-400ms tops. If you plan on having to spin *multiple seconds* on this, a different approach might be better.

(3) What other options do you have?

Consider if this third party request could take up to 30 minutes to complete. How would you handle this in your application? A common approach would be this:

```
- Browser client makes JSON request to your server.
- Server makes API call to service, gets back a 'request id'.
- Server sends back request id to browser client.
- Browser client enters loop, every 5 seconds, it sends server a message.
  - 'Did my request id complete yet?'
  - Server takes request id, asks service 'what is the answer?'
  - Send response back to browser.
- Browser client loops until the request is complete, then continues.
```

The user experience for this depends on the application. If the user has uploaded a large XML file to be processed, and the wait is 2-3 minutes, then you probably expect them to sit on the page while a progress bar slowly fills.

A different experience would be a page that the user can leave and come back to at will, this would be more like an application form they've submitted (they are checking if the status of their request to create a new DNS record has completed, for example).

Either way, behind the scenes, you've set it up so your *server* just accepts "start request" and "check the request" calls, and it's the client side code that you write to do the loop.